# The best way to bind list with other components in multi-threaded javafx application

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, fxml

I'am creating application to making screenshots via LAN. Server is 
listening for clients. When client is connect, new thread is created and it shoud be added to a list. Admin on server can pick client from list, make screenshot on its computer and screenshot is sent to server. The problem is the list. How to make this list available in many places in app and it was always synchronized with all components that use it ?

I am using JavaFX. I readed about SimpleListProperty, but the problem was "how to use this instance in server thread?". I've tried with singletone variations, dependencies injection like Guice, Ignite, Spring, but it was generated many troubles  and finally doesn't work :(

*Server implementation*

```
    public class SocketServer extends Thread {
private ServerSocket serverSocket;

@Override
public void run() {
    startServer();
}

private void startServer() {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2345);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (true) {
        try {
            new EchoClientHandler(serverSocket.accept()).run();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void stopServer() {
    try {
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class EchoClientHandler extends Thread {
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;

    public EchoClientHandler(Socket socket) {
        this.clientSocket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   //there shoud be somethink like:
   // list.add(this);
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

   //Getters and setters
```

*MainController*

```
public class MainController {

@FXML
private LogPaneController logPaneController;

@FXML
private ConnectionPaneController connectionPaneController;

@FXML
private ButtonsPaneController buttonsPaneController;

private Connector connectorImpl;

public void initialize() {
    createConnector();
}

private void createConnector() {
    ObservableList<Client> observableList = connectionPaneController.getConnectedClientsTable().getItems();
    connectorImpl.setClientSimpleListProperty(observableList);
}
```

*Connector*

```
public class ConnectorImpl implements Connector {
private List<SocketServer.EchoClientHandler> clientsThreads;
private SimpleListProperty<Client> clientSimpleListProperty;

public ConnectorImpl() {
}

public static Client parseThreadToClient(SocketServer.EchoClientHandler clientThread) {
    Socket socket = clientThread.getClientSocket();
    PrintWriter out = clientThread.getOut();
    BufferedReader in = clientThread.getIn();
    return new Client(socket, out, in);
}


@Override
public void connectNewClient(SocketServer.EchoClientHandler clientThread) {
    clientsThreads.add(clientThread);
    clientSimpleListProperty.add(parseThreadToClient(clientThread));
}
//Getters and setters
```

}

*App view*
[image: app view]

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question, but normally you would create an Observable List: `ObserveableList<ClientClass> clients = FXCollections.observableArrayList();` and then bind it to the TableView: `tableView.setItems(clients);` If you add now a new ClientClass to the Observable List it will automatically be shown in the TableView...

Comment: The ClientClass should look something like this: `public class ClientClass {
    private StringProperty client;

    public ClientClass(String client) {
        this.client = new SimpleStringProperty(client);
    }

    public StringProperty getClientProperty() {
        return client;
    }

    public String getClient() {
        return client.get();
    }

    public void setClient(String client) {
        this.client = new SimpleStringProperty(client);
    }
}`

Comment: @micpog90 Your set-method is incorrect.  Never replace the StringProperty.  Set the existing StringProperty’s value instead.  In fact, the private StringProperty field should be `final`.